# Как найти сокет пользователя в node js?

Tags: node.js, сокет, websocket, socket.io

Использую библиотеку `socketIo`. Для авторизации `passport + express`. У меня получилось идентифицировать сессию пользователя в `socketIo`.

Правда работает это в одностороннем порядке:

Найти express-cookie сессию пользователя через `socketIo` могу. А вот найти socket пользователя через его express-cookie - не выходит. Разве что в памяти хранить соотношение `userid = socket`; или циклом искать по всем сокетам.

Comment: Зачем вам при открытом соединении через socket.io нужно что-то от сессий express?

Comment: Так как большая функциональная часть написана на http. Socket используется для быстрой отправки сообщений.

Comment: Ну токен должен меняться каждый переход по сайту. И может быть открыто несколько страниц одновременно.